# PHP JS ajax submit form on page load and also trigger once another function succeeded

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parameter-passing, submit

I have 2 forms with each a JS script of which one loads some comments once a submit button is clicked, and the other script submits a comment.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 

$conn = mysqli_connect('dbserver', 'dbuser', 'dbpw', 'dbname') or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY date ASC";  

$rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//the following part will echo multiple individual forms, depending on the table content.
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {

    echo '
        <form action="load_comments.php" method="POST" id="form_' . $row["id"] . '" class="load_comments_form">

            <div id="result_comments_form_' . $row["id"] . '">
            <!--load all comments here-->
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="identifier" value="' . $row["identifier"] . '">
            <input type="hidden" name="translation_language" value="' . $row["language"] . '">

            <input type="submit" name="" value="Load / refresh comments" class="load-comments">
        </form>



        <form action="save_comment.php" method="POST" id="save_comment_form_' . $row["id"] . '" class="comment_form">
            <textarea rows="4" name="comment_content" class="textarea-comment"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="username" value="' . $row["username"] . '">
            <input type="hidden" name="identifier" value="' . $row["identifier"] . '">
            <input type="hidden" name="translation_language" value="' . $row["language"] . '">

            <input type="submit" name="" value="Send" class="submit-comment">
        </form>
    ';  
}

?>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!--Script 1: Load all comments-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".form").submit(function() {
        // Getting the form ID
        var  formID = $(this).attr('id');
        var formDetails = $('#'+formID);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'load_comments.php',
            data: formDetails.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {  
                // Inserting html into the result div
                $('#result_comments_'+formID).html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
            // Displaying if there are any errors
                $('#result_comments_'+formID).html(error);           
        }

    });
        return false;
    });

});
</script>


<!--Script 2: Save comment-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".save_comment_form").submit(function() {
        $('<div class="changes-saved_comment">&#10003; Comment sent.<br>Admin has been notified.</div>').insertAfter(this).fadeOut(6000);
        // Getting the form ID
        var  formID = $(this).attr('id');
        var formDetails = $('#'+formID);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'save_comment.php',
            data: formDetails.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {  
                // Inserting html into the result div
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
            // Displaying if there are any errors
        }

    });
        $('.textarea-comment').val(''); //clean textarea
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Here is a quick demo video of the current state:**

https://streamable.com/n94sa

As seen in the video currently I have to click the submit button of the first form / script in order to load the comments. Though, **the submit button** should remain there for triggering on demand, **but it should also trigger once on page load.**

The 2nd script submits a new comment.
As seen in the video, the comments are not refreshed automatically after submitting. **So I need the second script, once succeeded, to trigger the submit of the first form/script.**

Please keep in mind that there are multiple forms per page which are dynamically created with row["id"] and I am passing dynamically created parameters to both .php files with the help of formDetails.serialize().

Thank you.

Comment: So if i understand you want to reload all the comments after saving a new comment ?

Comment: yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

In save comment script call Load all comments `form submit` in the ajax success

```
    <!--Script 2: Save comment-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".save_comment_form").submit(function() {
        $('<div class="changes-saved_comment">&#10003; Comment sent.<br>Admin has been notified.</div>').insertAfter(this).fadeOut(6000);
        // Getting the form ID
        var  formID = $(this).attr('id');
        var formDetails = $('#'+formID);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'save_comment.php',
            data: formDetails.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $(".form").submit();//call this here in the success function
                // Inserting html into the result div
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
            // Displaying if there are any errors
        }

    });
        $('.textarea-comment').val(''); //clean textarea
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

**Update**

STEP: 1. For appending a form you first you need to add a parent element div for your result_comments_form_SOMEID div

```
echo '
    <form action="load_comments.php" method="POST" id="form_' . $row["id"] . '" class="load_comments_form">
        <div class="parent_div">
          <div id="result_comments_form_' . $row["id"] . '">
           <!--load all comments here-->
          </div>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="identifier" value="' . $row["identifier"] . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="translation_language" value="' . $row["language"] . '">

        <input type="submit" name="" value="Load / refresh comments" class="load-comments">
    </form>'
```

Step: 2. After saving the latest comment in `save_comment.php` you need to save the latest comment's id in a variable.

```
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;
```

Then you can fetch the last inserted record having `id` and the `comment` against this `$last_id`. After that, you need to echo it in the json format like this

```
echo json_encode($latest_record);
```

Then you will receive this json array in your jquery ajax success function and you can print it in the console for verification

Step: 3. You need to decode that json string in your jquery code like this

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
```

Now you can append this new record inside parent div in the ajax success like this.

```
 $( ".parent_div" ).append('<div id="result_comments_form_' + data.id + '">' + data.comment + '</div>');
```

Comment: It's not bad. Actually I hoped for a way for just reloading the particular div of the instance where I submit the comment. Instead, your solution updates all comment divs on the page. But nvm, this is acceptable too. Any suggestion for how to submit on the initial page load? This time indeed ALL instances on the page.

Comment: For this, you can append the comment in the new div with jQuery [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function in the ajax success

Comment: Could you please explain that more detailed? Maybe you could add that to your answer. That would be cool.

Comment: Can you define that exactly where are you populating your comments

Comment: See the "while" loop before the first form. It will create like 10 instances of the forms, each with an individual id. The comments should be loaded on page load in EVERY instance of <div id="result_comments_form_' . $row["id"] . '">. This is currently only possible with a manual submitting (see video in the initial post). But I need all comments of each instance of the form already loaded up on page load, without having to trigger it manually.

Comment: @DanielM I have updated my answer. You can check and ask freely if there is any query

Comment: Thank you. But I am a bit confused. What you added now is a way to load only the latest submitted comment, instead of refreshing/submitting all loading forms on the page, right? That's cool. I will try that. But what I actually meant in my last comment is a way to automatically submit / execute Script 1 (from my initial post) when the page gets loaded, in order to load all comments of the page on page load, without having to manually submit something in order to see all comments on page load. Your update doesn't include that, does it? Or am I missing something? Thx.

Comment: If I am not wrong you want to load your latest comment without pressing the load comment?

Comment: Yes, that TOO. And I get that you covered that. Thank you very much! But I wanted ALSO to load ALL comments on the whole page on all instances of the form to load automatically when loading the page. This is described in my initial post directly below the video link.

Comment: I think on the page loading it will do automatically

Comment: Kindly mark on tick button and upvote if it helps you. Thanks :)

Comment: And if you also want to populate your form instances with your comments while triggering the Load button then you also need to append the forms as I have done with the comment div

Answer (score 0):

For performance purpose you need to submit only the **sibling form** for which this comment belongs, by updating the *save-comment-form* a little bit like this

```
<form action="save_comment.php" method="POST" data-row-id="' . $row["id"] . '" id="save_comment_form_' . $row["id"] . '" class="comment_form">
    <textarea rows="4" name="comment_content" class="textarea-comment"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="' . $row["username"] . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="identifier" value="' . $row["identifier"] . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="translation_language" value="' . $row["language"] . '">

    <input type="submit" name="" value="Send" class="submit-comment">
</form>
```

and then update the answer above like this

```
<!--Script 2: Save comment-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".comment_form").submit(function() {
        $('<div class="changes-saved_comment">&#10003; Comment sent.<br>Admin has been notified.</div>').insertAfter(this).fadeOut(6000);
        // Getting the form ID
        var  formID = $(this).attr('id');
        var formDetails = $('#'+formID);
        var rowId = $(this).data('rowId');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('id'),
            data: formDetails.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#form_" + rowId).submit();//call this here in the success function
                // Inserting html into the result div
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
            // Displaying if there are any errors
            }

        });
        $(this).find('.textarea-comment').val('Hello');  //clean the related textarea
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```